# Invalid response received

Tags: contacts

I am trying to backup my iphone 6+ to iTunes.  It will not let me : could not connect to the iphone ( insert your name of phone) because an invalid response was received from the device.
I have researched on the web, it tells me to reset my network settings. - if I do this, will it remove all my contacts / photos/ notes before my last backup?

Comment: You can reset your network setting and it doesn't delete any of your data.  After the network reset, you'll have to login to any wireless network again; the reset deletes the login info.

Comment: Also, try using a different cord and make sure it's not connecting through a USB hub or similar.